# HttpResponseMessage can't serialize content

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have empty .net rest api, which accepts only `XML`.
If the controller method returns the class I want to serialize directly, there are no problems. But I want to use response wrapper, so that all controller methods return `HttpResponseMessage`.

So this works:
FooController.cs:

```
public FooResponse PostFoo(FooRequest foo)
{
  var fooVal = fooBll.GetFoo();
  return new FooResponse { Foo = fooVal;};
}
```

But this does not:
FooController.cs:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostFoo(FooRequest foo)
{
  var fooVal = fooBll.GetFoo();
  HttpResponseMesage response;
  response = fooBll.GetSuccessResponse(Url, new FooResponse {Foo = foovVal;});
  return response ;
}
```

ResponseBLL.cs:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetSuccessResponse(UrlHelper Url, object obj)
{
    this.requestMsg = HttpContext.Current.Items["MS_HttpRequestMessage"] as HttpRequestMessage;
    this.responseMsg = this.requestMsg.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, obj);
    this.responseMsg.Headers.Location = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
    return this.responseMsg;
}
```

FooBLL inherits ResponseBLL, that's why I can call `fooBll.GetSuccessResponse`.

In WebApiConfig.cs I have:

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
```

Error I get is

> The type FooResponse was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or
>   SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.

Now I know there have been already a lot of questions with this issue and trust me, I have gone through all of them with no success. I have tried `[DataContract], [DataMember], [Serializable]` and `[XmlInclude]` attribute in all possible combinations I could think of. `[XmlInclude(typeof(FooResponse))]` on FooBLL class, `[XmlInclude(typeof(FooBLL))]` on ResponseBLL and so on.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: It would be much cleaner to do this king of enrichment using action filter

Comment: @AlekseyL. Thanks, I will look into it. Basically why I wanted this wrapper was because that way controller could return different types of content, e.g. there is also `GetFailResponse` method, which instead of content would return info about error. Without it I can't do it as far as I see, I have to return `FooResponse` and nothing else.

Comment: this can be handled by exception filter or exception handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateResponse<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh969056(v=vs.118).aspx) is a generic method.  The `T Value` argument has to be correctly typed not declared as `object`, e.g.:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetSuccessResponse<T>(UrlHelper Url, T obj)
{
    this.requestMsg = HttpContext.Current.Items["MS_HttpRequestMessage"] as HttpRequestMessage;
    this.responseMsg = this.requestMsg.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, obj);
    this.responseMsg.Headers.Location = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
    return this.responseMsg;
}
```

This solution works because `XmlMediaTypeFormatter` constructs its `XmlSerializer` using `typeof(T)` rather than `value.GetType()`.  From the [source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/Formatting/XmlMediaTypeFormatter.cs):

```
    protected internal virtual object GetSerializer(Type type, object value, HttpContent content)
    {
        return GetSerializerForType(type);
    }
```

We can see that only the `type` (which is passed in to `WriteToStreamAsync()` as `typeof(T)` from [`ObjectContent<T>`](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/ObjectContentOfT.cs)) is used for serializer construction.  `object value` is not.  Microsoft possibly could have chosen to use `value.GetType()` instead, but did not.  The serializer then throws an exception because the actual type of the root object coming in (`typeof(Foo)` in this case) is not the same as type used to construct the serializer (`typeof(object)`) or one of the known types of `object`.

Comment: Thanks! Can't say that I understand fully why it works this way (noobie in xml), but that did it! But I guess I'll have to move to the direction @Alleksey L. pointed out. Meanwhile will use this.